# Getting error while creating SQL Server with UMI (User Manage Identity)

Tags: sql-server, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-managed-identity

I'm getting this error message while executing this Terraform code:

```
    resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql_server" {
      name                = var.sql_server_name
      resource_group_name = var.rg_name
      location            = var.rg_location
      version             = var.server_version
      administrator_login = var.admin_login
      administrator_login_password = "Rock2424"
      outbound_network_restriction_enabled = true
      minimum_tls_version                  = "1.2"
    
      dynamic "identity" {
    
        for_each = var.enable_manage_identity == false ? toset([]) : toset([1])
    
        content {
          type         = "UserAssigned"
          identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.id]
        }
      }
      primary_user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity[0].id
      azuread_administrator {
        login_username = var.ad_admin_server
        object_id      = var.ad_admin_server_object_id
      }
      tags = var.tags
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "user_assigned_identity" {
      count               = var.enable_manage_identity ? 1 : 0
      name                = "${var.sql_server_name}-identity"
      location            = var.rg_location
      resource_group_name = var.rg_name
    }
```

See error message below:

> Error: Missing required argument
>
> with azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server,
> on main.tf line 25, in resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql_server":
> primary_user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity[0].id
>
> "primary_user_assigned_identity_id": all of `identity.0.identity_ids,primary_user_assigned_identity_id` must be specified

Comment: you need a condition as well for the primary_user_assigned_identity_id ? something like that should work: `primary_user_assigned_identity_id = var.enable_manage_identity == false? null: azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.id`

Comment: That I have already tried and this did not worked. I believe the solution has nothing to do with the error